# Is this possible with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have tried everything i know in css to get this layout to work, I have not succeeded. Is it even possible to make these layouts (different resolutions) with flexbox.

It is easy with float, but I cannot do it with flex. Suggestions?

[image]

Snippet:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#container {
display: flex;
width: 500px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#green{background: green; width: 70%; height: 100px}
#yellow{background: yellow; width: 30%; height: 200px;}
#red{background: red; width: 70%; height: 70px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#green{width: 100%;}
#yellow{width: 50%; order: 3}
#red{width: 50%}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>

  <div id="red">^^^^ this space is the issue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the "white" frame div is the flex container that I am trying to force to make this behaviour, whilst I need this one to have dynamic height because the "yellow" and "red" divs are both dynamic content that grow "downwards" I'd still be very interested to see how you'd do it if the container's (white) height is defined?

Comment: Flexbox operates so called "flex lines", which behave similarly to lines of text containing inline-blocks. Each item belongs to one line only, it can be stretched to its height, but it can't span several lines. So the short answer to your question is "No, it's not possible". Hovewer, you can kind of emulate this by switching `flex-direction` from row to column and adjusting the `order`s of the items using Media Query.

Answer (score 2):

See if this would help

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.topBox,
.leftBox,
.rightBox {
  padding: 5px;
}

.topBox {
  background: green
}

.leftBox {
  background: red
}

.rightBox {
  background: yellow
}

.row {
  display: flex
}

.leftBox,
.rightBox {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 30%;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  .rightBox {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .leftBox {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topBox">
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
      content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
      versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </div>
    <div class="rightBox">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
      content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
      versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot accept this as a solution, though I have to say, A for effort. I dont need this "solved" its a question of "can it be done with flex". Cheating with absolute, is, i guess till doing it with flex so you get an upvote, but cant mark as a solution :P

It can easily be solved with a simple float, or like you did yourself, Im trying to solve it "clean" whilst sticking to flex because we use flex in our project to control flow, not grid, tables or float.

Comment: @Dellirium The second layout can't be done without it, at first I thought it can, but nope. Another way would be to rotate the container then adjust its children.

Comment: @VXp then I guess the answer is "it  cant be done with flexbox"

Comment: @Dellirium I'm afraid no.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this and go on from here, the second layout needs some help of the *positioning*:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#container > div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#green {background: green; flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px); position: relative}
#red {background: red; flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px)}
#yellow {background: yellow; flex: 1}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #green {flex: 1}
  #red {width: calc(50% - 15px); height: calc(50% - 5px); position: absolute; left: calc(50%); bottom: 5px}
  #yellow {flex: initial; width: calc(50% - 10px); height: 50%}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="green">Green</div>
  <div id="red">Red ^^^^ this space is the issue</div>
  <div id="yellow">Yellow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: container rotating, never would i ever think of that, lol, though I guess that is even more hacky then adding absolute position. Either way, I will conclude that it cannotbe done without it and leave it at that, upvote for effort. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would use native w3c css grid layout, witch are supported by most navigator now. Css grid permit to set horizontal and vertical alignements.

"Like tables, grid layout enables an author to align elements into columns and rows. However, many more layouts are either possible or easier with CSS grid than they were with tables. For example, a grid container's child elements could position themselves so they actually overlap and layer, similar to CSS positioned elements. "

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
You will find many videos on css grid

Comment: Yeh with grid its easily doable, same like with float, goal is to do it with flex, or rather goal is to see if it is possible to do it with flex.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox items, like inline-blocks and unlike Grid items and floats, can't span multiple lines of items. That's why the only way to achieve the layout you need using Flexbox is using different flex directions — column for wide screens and row for narrow screen. The column flex direction, in turn, needs the height of the container to be known in order to distribute items between columns correctly.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#container {
display: flex;
width: 500px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
height: 300px;
}
#green{background: green; width: 70%; height: 100px; }
#yellow{background: yellow; width: 30%; height: 200px; }
#red{background: red; width: 70%; height: 70px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#container { flex-direction: row; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
#green{width: 100%; }
#yellow{width: 50%; }
#red{width: 50%; height: auto; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: VXp suggested a solution like this, though ultimately, having fixed column height is not an option, the whole goal of this layout is to let both red and yellow containers grow  indefinitively, whilst keeping both of them "near the start" of the container for easy access. Think of blogposts vs news or any other two informatio heavy lists with semi-equal values. Upvoting for effort though. Seems its just not doable with flex and we should probably leave it at that.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, its possible with flex box. What you want to do is like :**

**Layout 1 :**

Divide the **Layout** into two naming - **left-container** & **right-container**, where **green box** and **red box** will be in **left container** & place **yellow box** in **right-container**.
And apply `display: flex to layout` So that you can achieve it perfectly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-container {
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.green-box, .red-box, .yellow-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.green-box {
  background: green;
  height: 50%;
}
.red-box {
  background: red;
  height: 49%;
}
.right-container {
  width: 39%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.yellow-box {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="red-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="yellow-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't support the other layout though

Comment: @Dellirium You mean other layout with two rows? [Here](https://codepen.io/prasanthlalapeta/pen/vrxJxQ) is the link for second layout :)